# How to convert table from 1d to 2d in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a plugin or a method to convert 1d table to 2d in Excel?

Like that:

Input:

```
Key1 Key2 Value
A    A    Q
A    B    W
A    B    E
A    C    R
B    A    T
B    B    Y
....
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
A    Q    W E  R
B    T    Y    ...
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that pairs of key1&key2 are not unique you will have to use UDF to concatenate strings based on criteria.

The solution below uses `ConcatIf` function defined here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552704/sumif-for-strings

I assume that your data is in cells `A1:C7` with headers.

In column D create a "combined key" column using the formula `=A2&B2`. Use a separator between keys if this may lead to ambiguous combined key.

Enter unique key1 values in column E starting from row 2. Enter unique key2 values in row 1 starting from column F. Enter the following formula `=ConcatIF($D$2:$D$7, $E2&F$1, $C$2:$C$7, " ")` in cell `F2`.